# On any websites search bar, is there a way to make it recognize special symbols such as the # sign?

Tags: search, web, search-engines, symbols

I'm looking up flashcards on a website and predictably it ignores the # sign in C#, so my results are all over the place.  Is there any kind of escape character voodoo that works with search engines to get accurate results?

Comment: I believe most websites/search engines use a sort of encoding when it comes to special chars.  For example, if I search "test'search" in google, the URL displays that I've searched "test%27search"